# Jupyter in VS Code - how to change inline code code render in markdown?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, colors, themes, jupyter

I have an annoying problem, which I cannot find a solution to.

I'm using VS Code + Jupyter as my go-to tool for python projects. I've found out how to customize all colours / styles in it, except for inline code render in markdown. See 2 examples below.

Does anyone know what are the properties (settings.json?) that I need to use to change background and border settings of how VS Code renders inline code?

Like `this for example` - grey background, no border.

[This is markdown code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb7sS.png)

[It renders like this in my selected theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMiYD.png)

[But this is how one of the default themes renders it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4DoF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some additional functionality. As @JialeDu mentioned, it looks like there is no option to change border / background color of how inline code is rendered.

However, you can change the render color. In `setting.json` under `"workbench.colorCustomizations":` you need to add:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "textPreformat.foreground": "#deba7bf5"
},
```

where `#deba7bf5` is a color you can pick.

Answer (score 0):

The code style in the editor can be modified by the following configuration.

```json
// settings.json file
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Default High Contrast]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope":"markup.inline.raw",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#00ff95",
                    "fontStyle": "bold"
                }
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

Original theme style:

[image]

*Theme: Dark High Contrast*

After adding configuration:

[image]

*Theme: Dark High Contrast*

However, the interface style finally presented by Markdown is different under each theme, and no way to modify it has been found yet.

[image]

*Theme: Dark High Contrast*

[image]

*Theme: Quiet Light*

Comment: Hey JialeDu! Thank you for the quick reply!


"However, the interface style finally presented by Markdown is different under each theme, and no way to modify it has been found yet." --> That's what I was looking for :(


Still, in your example color of the rendered code is different - one is brown another is red. Does it mean that at least this parameter can be influenced somehow?

Comment: Yes, but this should be related to the theme. I searched for information, but I can't find a way to modify it directly. Maybe you can get the effect you want by switching themes or [creating your own](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#create-a-new-color-theme)([theme-color](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color)).